# Rust/Serde: serialize external struct to json camelcase

Tags: json, rust, serde

I am working on some code that takes a struct returned by an external library, serializes it to json, and serializes the json to protobuf using `pbjson`. The external library uses serde and implements `Serialize`, but the json that is returned is snake case. The problem is that `pbjson` is expecting the json to be camelcase.

How can I get a camelcase version of the serde json object? (ie configure the external library to use something like `#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]` or to convert the json keys to camelcase?)

Note: I am working with many remote structs that in total add up to almost 2k lines of code. I would like to avoid recreating these types locally if possible.

Comment: https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html

Comment: @PitaJ I've seen that, but was hoping to not have to go that route since `Serialize` and `Deserialize` have already been implemented in the external crate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this? Basically you just need to turn the foreign items into items of your own type and then serialize those.

```rust
// foreign struct
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Foreign {
    the_first_field: u32,
    the_second_field: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
struct Mine {
    the_first_field: u32,
    the_second_field: String,
}

impl From<Foreign> for Mine {
    fn from(
        Foreign {
            the_first_field,
            the_second_field,
        }: Foreign,
    ) -> Self {
        Self {
            the_first_field,
            the_second_field,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // only used to construct the foreign items
    let in_json = r#"[{"the_first_field": 1, "the_second_field": "second"}]"#;

    let foreign_items = serde_json::from_str::<Vec<Foreign>>(in_json).unwrap();

    let mine_items = foreign_items.into_iter().map(Mine::from).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let out_json = serde_json::to_string(&mine_items).unwrap();

    println!("{}", out_json);  // [{"theFirstField":1,"theSecondField":"second"}]
}
```

Comment: This will work, but will also require a lot of work. I updated the question to explain why. I will hold off on accepting for now in case there is a better solution. I appreciate you taking the time to come up with this solution :)

Comment: In that case you can serialize to JSON, deserialize to a HashMap, manually titlecase the keys yourself (using the [heck](https://docs.rs/heck/latest/heck/) crate), and serialize back. Poor performance, but it'll work.